# Possible to use a MySites field as a Custom List column?

Tags: my-site, custom-list

Ok, odd request incoming....

Is it possible to add a field from our User Profile information in MySites as a column on a custom list?

So lets say Mr. SoAndSo creates a new list item....This column would then automatically fill in his Work Phone field information in this column.

My guess is it would be easier to just have them type it in...but hey I figured it was worth asking at least :)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to edit the **Created By** field on a list to show alternative fields (such as Mobile Number) by changing the **Show Field** option.

You could then change the field's display name and edit the views to display it as required.

Comment: Hmm I see. What if I need both the Created By field showing Name(with presence) AND... a Created By field showing (Mobile Number)

Comment: Well, I was going to propose a standalone User field with similar settings, but you can't assign them a default value (such as [Me]) unfortunately. The only other even more cowboyish and unreliable option would be to use **Modified By** in the same way.

Comment: Or create an ItemAdded Event Receiver to populate the default value, or whatever other details you felt like.

Comment: Darn I really need both Created By and Modified By to stay as they are. Would of been great to be able to show Name(with presence) and Mobile Number.